# Unable to run the sample application for google cloud platform

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am just starting off on google-cloud-platform. I have created an account and a project on cloud console. I was trying to run some of the sample apps provided.
I started with the sample app for cloud storage provided at:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/cloud-client

I have installed apache maven 3.5.0 on my PC.
I followed the steps provided in the link, that is I gave the following commands:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

and then

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.storage.QuickstartSample -Dexec.args="my-bucket-name"
```

The first command succeeded. However, the second command failed.
I got the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-15T18:27:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project storage-google-cloud-samples: An exception occured while executing the Java class. connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Now, the computer where I was running this command on, is behind a proxy. However, my proxy settings have been set in the file conf/settings.xml, also when I ran the first command, it successfully downloaded some packages, so I'm not sure if it is due to some proxy issue, however to check, I tried it on another machine, which is not behind a proxy.

I gave the same two commands. The first one succeeded and the second failed again, with the following (different) error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:02 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-15T18:22:31+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (d
efault-cli) on project storage-google-cloud-samples: An exception occured while
executing the Java class. 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

So my queries are:

1. What could be the cause for the error in the first case? Is it something to do with proxy settings? If yes, then where/how should I specify the settings?
2. What could be the cause for the error in the second case where I am not behind any proxy?
3. Am i missing some step here?
4. Also , if you look at the source for this sample app, there is just a single file which basically creates a bucket. The bucket is passed as an argument from command line. Now, as per my understanding, first there needs to a project in the cloud console to create any resources. So where will this bucket be created? As in shouldn't we be specifying the project-ID where this bucket is to be created?

Comment: Is there a google group for this?

Comment: As per the link https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/community,
they recommend stack overflow for technical questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You're missing the credentials, the example relies on to invoke the desired Google Cloud APIs. Using `Application Default Credentials` is the recommended approach when using the Google Cloud APIs using any of the Client libraries.

## Longer version

The example relies on [`Application Default Credentials`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) ([as explained in the `README.md`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/README.md#credentials-example) of the github repo you're using).

> ## [How the Application Default Credentials work](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork)
>
> You can get Application Default Credentials by making a single client
>   library call. The credentials returned are determined by the
>   environment the code is running in. Conditions are checked in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. The environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is checked. If this variable is specified it should point to a file that
>      defines the credentials. The simplest way to get a credential for this
>      purpose is to create a Service account key in the Google API Console:
>
>    a. Go to the [API Console Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/credentials).
>
>    b. From the project drop-down, select your project.
>
>    c. On the Credentials page, select the Create credentials drop-down,
>      then select Service account key.
>
>    d.From the Service account drop-down, select an existing service
>      account or create a new one.
>
>    e. For Key type, select the JSON key option, then select Create. The
>      file automatically downloads to your computer.
>
>    f. Put the *.json file you just downloaded in a directory of your
>      choosing. This directory must be private (you can't let anyone get
>      access to this), but accessible to your web server code.
>
>    g. Set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to
>      the path of the JSON file downloaded.
> 2. If you have installed the Google Cloud SDK on your machine and have run the command [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/auth/application-default/login), your
>      identity can be used as a proxy to test code calling APIs from that
>      machine.
> 3. If you are running in Google App Engine production, the built-in service account associated with the application will be used.
> 4. If you are running in Google Compute Engine production, the built-in service account associated with the virtual machine instance
>      will be used.
> 5. If none of these conditions is true, an error will occur.